# JS Regex: match list of phrases exactly (including hash symbols)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of phrases, and am trying to detect if a string of text contains a full phrase. I currently am using the following regex:

```
var arrOfWords = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo bar']
var regEx = new RegExp('\\b(' + arrOfWords.join('|') + ')\\b', 'gi')

console.log(regEx)
/\b(foo|bar|foo bar)\b/gi
```

I used `\b` because I didn't want to include substrings, but rather the complete word/phrase, i.e.
"foo" should not match with "foobar", but should match "I like foo"

This works great, however, word boundaries, `\b`, ignore phrases that begin with `#`, as `\b` starts the boundary at alphanumeric characters.

So if "#hashtag" is in the array, it will only match if the string being tested has "hashtag", not "#hashtag"

What I'm really looking for would be a regex that matches the entire phrase as specified in the array, including symbols and hashes. Or maybe a solution that can work around this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, JS doesn't have lookbehind, so it is impossible to match on properties of previous character without including that character into the match (except by `\b`, which is, as you note, of very limited use). If this is acceptable to you, you can have:

```
/(?:^|\W)(foo|bar|foo bar|#hashtag)(?=$|\W)/
```

and only deal with the first capture group. This is guaranteed to not overlap if you only want full words/phrases, as there is guaranteed to be a non-word separator.

NB: if `arrOfWords` contains strings with regexp-meaningful characters, they will be interpreted as such; so `foo.bar` will be matching `foosbar`. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) on how to avoid it.

> Hey, this is 90% there for me, thanks. Just to nitpick, I noticed that if `arrOfWords` contains `#hashtag`, it will match with `##hashtag` in the string. Is there a way of matching only if the number of hashes is exact?

Then you need to be explicit about what's a word and what's a non-word character, and replace `\W` with that.

```
/(?:^|[^\w#'-])(foo|bar|foo bar|#hashtag)(?=$|[^\w#'-])/
```

Comment: Hey, this is 90% there for me, thanks. Just to nitpick, I noticed that if `arrOfWords` contains `#hashtag`, it will match with `##hashtag` in the string. Is there a way of matching only if the number of hashes is exact?

Comment: Looks like you need `/(?:^|\s)(foo|bar|foo bar|#hashtag)(?=$|\s)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That might or might not be too restrictive (and only OP can tell). For example, `Eleanor said "#hashtag is trending"` would not match with yours, but would with mine.